# What causes this? rdplot Error in R: Error in seq.default(x_min, c, jump_l) : invalid '(to - from)/by'

Tags: r, regression

I am trying to use some very simple data in rdplot but I keep getting the error: `Error in seq.default(x_min, c, jump_l) : invalid '(to - from)/by'` I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35003910/completely-stumped-about-this-error-error-in-seq-defaultstart-at-nrowdata/35036850) response from a diffrent post on Stack Overflow but can seem to apply the fix to the rdplot function.  does anyone know how can this be fixed?
The actual code I am using is:

```
library(rdrobust)

rdplot(y = dt$treated, x = dt$score)
```

---

Reproducibility:
[Here](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/79258565cf6428cc38cca307d20f923320201020220309/0a9263) is a sample of my data, as I've said it is fairly common data. So far I have found a couple of things:

1. There are multiple subsets of the observations that seem to cause problems
2. Changing the `nbins` or `binselect` arguments  from their default will fix the problem
3. The first time you get an error is on the set 1:1463, however using only observations 2:1464 is OK.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: @MrFlick, thanks I have included a sample of my data. As I said its fairly simple data so I don't know why I am getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

The recent rdrobust version 1.0.1 should take care of this error.

Comment: could you provide more details?